# Possible to Use MXNet gluon.Trainer without a Neural Network?

Tags: python, mxnet

I am trying to use the graph structure of MXNet to speed up some calculations, and I am currently trying to mimic behavior that I have already implemented in PyTorch. However, I am confused on how to properly do this, be it with [`gluon.Trainer`](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/gluon/gluon.html#mxnet.gluon.Trainer) or some other method.

To explain with an example, what I have working in PyTorch is the following (slightly modified to try to give the simplest example), and I want to translate this to MXNet.

```
import torch.optim


def unconstrained_fit(objective, data, pdf, init_pars, tolerance):
    init_pars.requires_grad = True
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([init_pars])
    max_delta = None
    n_epochs = 10000
    for _ in range(n_epochs):
        loss = objective(init_pars, data, pdf)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        init_old = init_pars.data.clone()
        optimizer.step()
        max_delta = (init_pars.data - init_old).abs().max()
        if max_delta < tolerance:
            break
    return init_pars
```

As [The Straight Dope points out in the PyTorch to MXNet cheatsheet](https://github.com/zackchase/mxnet-the-straight-dope/blob/master/cheatsheets/pytorch_gluon.md#pytorch-optimizer-vs-gluon-trainer), in MXNet one would usually be able to use a Trainer where one would use an [optimizer in PyTorch](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/optim.html). However, I don't understand how to properly initialize the Trainer in my case, as where one would usually do something along the lines of

```
trainer = gluon.Trainer(net.collect_params(), 'adam')
```

I assume that I will need to collect the parameters myself as I don't have a neural network that I want to use, but rather `objective` that I want to minimize. I am confused on how to do this properly, as the below is obviously not correct.

```
import mxnet as mx
from mxnet import gluon, autograd

def unconstrained_fit(self, objective, data, pdf, init_pars, tolerance):
    ctx = mx.cpu()
    # How to properly do this chunck?
    init_pars = mx.gluon.Parameter('init_pars',
                                   shape=init_pars.shape,
                                   init=init_pars.asnumpy().all)
    init_pars.initialize(ctx=ctx)
    optimizer = mx.optimizer.Adam()
    trainer = gluon.Trainer([init_pars], optimizer)
    ###
    max_delta = None
    n_epochs = 10000
    for _ in range(n_epochs):
        with autograd.record():
            loss = objective(init_pars, data, pdf)
        loss.backward()
        init_old = init_pars.data.clone()
        trainer.step(data.shape[0])
        max_delta = (init_pars.data - init_old).abs().max()
        if max_delta < tolerance:
            break
    return init_pars
```

I am clearly misunderstanding something basic, so if anyone can point me to something clarifying that would be helpful. Even more helpful would be if someone understands what I am asking and is able to summarize why what I am doing is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The Trainer in gluon is simply updating a set of parameters according to an optimizer. You need to pass it the parameters that you want to optimize in your objective function. A couple of points already:

- The `Trainer` takes a `ParameterDict`, not a `Parameter[]`.
- You need to use `.data()` to get the data of a Parameter, rather than `.data`.

If you posted your objective function, error logs, I might be able to help you further.

Also using a `Trainer` is not compulsory. Have a look at this tutorial: https://github.com/zackchase/mxnet-the-straight-dope/blob/master/chapter02_supervised-learning/linear-regression-scratch.ipynb It is performing linear regression optimization from scratch, using only `NDArray` and `autograd`.

One key point is to attach a gradient to your parameters, to allocate memory so that the gradient can stored when using `autograd.record()` (here two params, `w` and `b`):

```
w = nd.random_normal(shape=(num_inputs, num_outputs), ctx=model_ctx)
b = nd.random_normal(shape=num_outputs, ctx=model_ctx)
params = [w, b]
for param in params:
    param.attach_grad()
```

Then after calling `loss.backward()` you can access the gradient of each parameters and update them using the SGD formula like this:

```
for param in params:
    param[:] = param - lr * param.grad
```